# What amount of force is needed to topple a person?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Assuming no sliding and that the shoulder is 1.2m from the feet, what force is required to topple a person weighing 70 Kg standing with his feet spread 0.9 m? If possible, please include an explanation about your answer.

Comment: I'd imagine there would be a difference between what steady force is needed and what would be needed as a sudden impulse catching them off guard. Also, are we toppling them over backwards or sideways?

Comment: i don't really know that is what the problem says and nothing more..but let's say sideway if it is needed

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: not really..i was reading a physic book of a friend and this problem took my interest but i just can't get the answer and it is driving me crazy

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: rules of static equilibrium,i believe it should be those rules

Comment: I agree that the rules of static equilibrium should proabably be used: treat the "person" as a solid plank. The completely general problem admits people who know how to react in the style of soft martial arts whose ability to not fall when pushed can be quite surprising, both in "party trick" situation and in more dynamic exercises like push hands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approximate the person with a brick with a width of 0.9 m and a height of 1.2 meter. The torque around the tipping point caused by gravity is $mg\cdot l$, where $l$ is the horizontal distance from the tipping point to the center of mass of the brick, i.e. half the brick width assuming it has a uniform density. You need to counteract this torque by exerting a horizontal force at the top. The torque caused by your force is $F\cdot h$. To sum up:

$$
mgl=Fh \Rightarrow F=\frac{mgl}{h}\approx\frac{70\cdot9.8\cdot0.45}{1.2}\approx257 \mathrm{N}
$$

However, many of the assumptions made here may not be realistic in a real world person-toppling event.

Edit: The solution above assumes that the toppling force is horizontal. If you can apply the force at an angle you can get a slightly longer lever, maximally the length of the brick diagonal:
$$
d=\sqrt{1.2^2+0.9^2}=1.5
$$
This gives the smallest possible toppling force:
$$
F=\frac{mgl}{d}\approx\frac{70\cdot9.8\cdot0.45}{1.5}\approx206 \mathrm{N}
$$

Answer (score 0):

- The counterclockwise torque $T_a$ about this point produced by the applied force is:

$$T_a=F_a \cdot h =F_a \cdot 1.2 m$$

- The opposite restoring torque $T_w$ due to the person’s weight is:

$$T_w=W\cdot L=W \cdot 0.9 m$$

- as the mass m of the person is 70 kg, his weight $W$ is:

$$W=mg=75 \cdot 9.8=686 N$$
(Here $g$ is the gravitational acceleration)

- The person is on the verge of toppling when the magnitudes of these
  two torques are just equal,

$$T_a=T_w$$

$$F_a \cdot 1.2 m=686 N \cdot 0.9 m$$

Therefore, the force required to topple an erect person is :

$$F_a=514.5 N$$

Comment: A person's weight is typically centered over their feet. By using a length of 0.9m to compute the weight torque, you're assuming that the person's entire weight is supported by one foot only, and that you're trying to topple them over the other foot. That doesn't really make sense, as it would require the second foot and leg to be completely massless. A better model, as seen in the accepted answer, would use 0.45m as the torque arm length, which assumes weight evenly spread over both feet 0.9m apart.

Answer (score 0):

Doing moments (sum of torques) about point A on both diagrams, the Force $F$ needed is from

$$Fh=70g\times \frac{d}{2}$$

$$F=70g\times \frac{d}{2h}$$

[image]

So to topple a person sideways (diagram 1) by pushing at the shoulder it's about $\frac{70\times 10\times 0.9}{2 \times 1.2} =263N$.

However as every mean Ninja-physicist will know, it's easier to topple a person by pulling their hair forwards or backwards (diagram 2).

Now the $h$ is larger e.g. $1.6$ and the $d$ is much smaller $0.3$, then it's about $\frac{70\times 10\times 0.3}{2 \times 1.6} = 66N$